postgres can't drop table even though there are no updates going on
I have an app that contantly creates small tables and has to drop them.
For example, let's say it creates the table WORLD1 which is then used for a short time, then the app creates the next table WORLD2, populates it, and then it has to drop WORLD1.
Clients that connect to the app will only read table data and never need to change it and they are always aware the current table is WORLD2 via another lookup table.  All clients do is SELECT data and no UPDATES.
The problem is that when I try to DROP the WORLD1 table, it would hang.  Can SELECT statement cause a lock to remain forever even though I confirmed all of the clients are now reading from WORLD2.
The only way I can drop WORLD1 is to kill all the clients.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Strange data model, but Yes, a select using a table makes it impossible to drop that table at the same moment. Check pg_stat_activity to see what is going on and what process has a lock on this table.

but all the clients have stopped reading from the old table and are already on the new table (confirmed via logs at the clients)

Did you check pg_stat_activity? That will show you what’s going on

A table can't be dropped while there are open transactions that reference the table. It doesn't matter whether the referencing statement is SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or TRUNCATE, nor does it matter if the statement has affected any rows. It also doesn't matter whether or not the referencing statement has completed so long as the transaction is still open.

I was able to fix this problem by making every client do a commit() after their select(). I never knew I had to commit a look-up query. Problem solved!

I was able to fix this problem by making every client do a commit() after their select().  I never knew I had to commit a look-up query.  Problem solved!

Check your client library documentation for an autcommit setting and switch it on. What language and library are you using?
